# Update a single mysql row if another row hasn't been updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following `select` statement, which returns the first occurrence where `dog=0` after the `insert_time`:

```
SELECT mammal, id
FROM mytable
WHERE dog = 0 
  AND insert_time > "2012-02-09 00:00:00"
LIMIT 0, 1
```

I then want to update that row so that `mammal = 1` ONLY if mammal doesn't already `=1`. The only way that I would currently know how to do this would be to fetch the array in PHP, check the mammal element and then run another mysql statement to `UPDATE` the row.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mammal = 1
WHERE id = selectidfromabove
```

Is there a way I can do this all in one mysql statement, perhaps wrapping the `SELECT` statement above in an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` will not provide you a dependable resultset.  You'll be updating a record at random every time.  Please explain more (in plain English) about what you're actually trying to do, as I think the answers you will get won't do what you actually want to do.  That is to say, are you sure you only want to update ONE record with this?  It would seem to me you would want to update all records that match the criteria, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do exactly what you proposed:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mammal=1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM mytable
    WHERE dog = 0 
        AND insert_time > "2012-02-09 00:00:00"
    LIMIT 0, 1
);
```

Note: your original select query was modified to only select id.

Comment: There is a `LIMIT 0, 1` FWIW.

Comment: To the OP - note that this will update a **completely random single record** from the matching results... although it's exactly what you asked for.  I propose that you may actually want something different, though.

Comment: Hey Smose, I'll be using ORDER BY insert_time to make sure I'm getting the record immediately following the given timestamp